# In which way I can send the CSV file to somewhere then make some process then return json data?

Tags: javascript, php, tomcat, d3.js, server

I am doing the dc.js visualisation data, and d3-force-layout. dc.js is based on the d3 and crossfilter and dc can handle the csv file as the input file but the d3-force-layout can only consider the json file as a input file. So I am thinking to send the CSV files to some where using java program convert the csv file into json file, then send it back for d3-force layout using. I have tried php and javaEE to build webpage. but d3.js and dc.js cannot be loaded on the apache server and tomcat server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrqn5.png)

```
        <script src="JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/crossfilter-master/crossfilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
    <script src="JS/d3-3.5.17/d3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/dc.js-2.0.2/dc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/d3-queue/d3-queue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This the code how I load the js libraries.
This is the JS send to request.

```
$('#files').change(function(){
var q = d3.queue();
var fileNames = "";
for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
    fileNames += ", " + this.files[i].name;
    q.defer(d3.csv, this.files[i].name);
}
q.awaitAll(drawDC);
$.get("http://localhost:8080/Charting/ChartingServlet?files="+fileNames, drawForceLayout);
// drawForceLayout('data.json');
$("#fileNames").html('');
if(this.files.length > 1)
    $("#fileNames").html(fileNames.substring(2));
});

function drawForceLayout(jsonFile){
    //start to draw
}
```

I also made a servlet to handle the request get the files, convert to json sent it back.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(request.getParameterMap().containsKey("files")) {
        String files = request.getParameter("files");
        System.out.println(files.toString());

        ////call the java program to convert CSV files to json then sent the file name or the content back.

        response.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().append("data.json");
    }
}
```

[This is the Tomcat server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUbjU.png)
The index.html is the main page.

My question is how do I achieve this, did I do something wrong with these servers?

Comment: *" the d3-force-layout can only consider the json file as a input file"* This is wrong. You certainly can create a force-directed based on a CSV file.

Comment: Could you please see the links here http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/. The data I need from the csv file, I need to make some extraction.

Comment: Well, I suggest you post a question with your CSV and the problems you're facing to create your force directed with that CSV.

Comment: Did you read my answer below, and did you down-vote it? The root cause of your question is that you say that the force layout is not able to deal with a CSV file. This is not correct and the block that I have linked is precisely an example that shows how to feed csv to the force layout. Doing a conversion on the server-side is overkill: d3.js provides all you need to convert between csv and json.

Comment: No,  I did not down-vote your answer. I up-voted you answer. I don not know why you answer is keeping going down.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this block: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2949937. You will see the `d3.csv` function in action.

Comment: No, I did not down-vote your answer. I up-voted you answer. I don not know why you answer is keeping going down.